# Variable interator in for cycle

Tags: kotlin, for-loop

This is my example

```
for (i in array.indices)
{
    if (array[i] == 10)
    {
        i -= 2//have error here
    }
}
```

How can i make 'i' variable mutable?

Comment: What problem you want to solve? Please add more details to your question.

Comment: What do you mean for it to be mutable? Do you want to rewind your iteration and replay the last two steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Use `while` loop instead:

```kotlin
var i = 0
while (i < array.size) {
    if (array[i] == 10) {
        i -= 2
    }

    ...

    i++
}
```

Comment: Yes, i know about while cycle. I want to write something similar with for var y in (0 ..< 10) in Swift